# Issues with updating a word document using docx

Tags: python, docx

I really am very new to this so please be gentle. I've been looking for a couple of hours at how to sort this out. Essentially I am trying to open a word document, find the "X" character in a very simple table I have put in, then update it to whatever the user inputs. The last thing I did here was make this a function and call it, to see if I could get round some issues I thought I was having with it correctly capturing the user's input. It looks like the below in IDLE. I'm trying to get X replaced by Cabbage, so this is what the below shows. The issue is that after I run this I open the word document (for the Nth time now) and it just is not updating to say "Cabbage". What might I be doing wrong here? I am not getting any error messages to go on. I've tried this without the function and function call, but it isn't having it:

```
>>> import os
>>> from docx import Document
>>> import docx
>>> doc=Document('Temp.docx')
>>> def tupdate(rep):
    for table in doc.tables:
        for col in table.columns:
            for cell in col.cells:
                for p in cell.paragraphs:
                     if 'X' in p.text:
                        p.text.replace("X", rep)

                        
>>> rep = input()
Cabbage
>>> tupdate(rep)
>>> doc.save('Temp.docx')
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am using the latest version of python on windows.

Thank you.

Comment: `p.text.replace("X", rep)` does not do an in-place substitution.

Comment: Thank you. This was one of my concerns. Could you point me at what might achieve that?

Comment: See if you can set `p.text = p.text.replace("X", rep)`

Answer (score 0):

`p.text.replace("X", rep)` does not do an in-place substitution.

I've tested the code below and I was able to replace Xs with Zs.

```
import os

from docx import Document

doc = Document('Temp.docx')
rep = 'Z'  # input()

for table in doc.tables:
    for col in table.columns:
        for cell in col.cells:
            for p in cell.paragraphs:
                if 'X' in p.text:
                    p.text = p.text.replace("X", rep)

doc.save('Temp.docx')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with this.